# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

If I type "_.template($('#pranks-list').html())" on Chrome JS console it's works as well

```
>> _.template($('#pranks-list').html())
function (a){return e.call(this,a,b)}
```

app.js
    // Views

```
window.PranksListView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#pranks-list').html())
});
```

Index.html

```
  <script type="text/html" id="pranks-list">
    <li><a href='#pranks/<%= id %>'><%= name %></a></li>
  </script>

  </body>
```

Why I get this error on this line??

```
template: _.template($('#pranks-list').html())
```

Comment: just search for replace in those scripts, you can see which variable is becoming null, or put some code here

Comment: I have never seen html in `<script>` tags before. Are you sure you don't want a div instead?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko: It's a pretty common way to store templates. With a `type` that will not cause some scripting engine to execute it it's a great way and much cleaner than invisible divs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing the whole code, but you are probably trying to run `_.template($('#pranks-list').html())` before the dom is created and the node is there.
Usually its a good practice to render the template on render time when you have the template variables ready:

```
_.template($('#pranks-list').html(), {id: 'foo', name: 'bar'});
```

Comment: It's works! I moved down all JS files (backbonejs,underscorejs, jquery) just before </body> and all works as well! Thank you man! :)